# How to create basic game item attributes

Tags: objective-c, attributes

I'm trying to make an RPG-type game, without the map part, it's basically a series of battles.  The battles are turn based and have limited animation, mainly just text info.  It's the first game I'm making and I don't have plans to distribute.  Basically I have no idea how to set up my game.  I don't know how to store what level the player is, which enemy they are up to in the story line, what there weapons are and the attributes are, etc.  I'm not looking for code I just need to know what to research, how to set this all up.

Answer (score 1):

How much experience programming do you have?  If this is truly your very first game, it may be a bit too difficult for you.  The only reason I think this is because by the time I started creating games of this complexity, I had a firm grasp on how to structure them.  On the other hand, if you really think that you're ready for this, grab some paper and a pencil and start planning.  Personally, I find the trick to planning an application to be asking myself "What makes sense?"  For example, it makes sense for there to be some sort of application class, something that controls the program.  It makes sense for there to be a Player class, which holds information such as the level, different stats, health, etc.  It makes sense for there to be some sort of AbstractEnemy class, from which different enemy types inherit from.  Make some sort of chart showing how things will relate with each other and which classes will handle what.